# How to launch Applications without URL Schemes and without touching the icon on a non jailbroken iDevice?

Tags: ios, iphone-privateapi, springboard

I like to build an app to view specific apps without URL scheme  I have heard about a Framework called SpringBoardServices but there is always a Linker Error

As far I use this code with the SpringBoardServices.h file

SpringBoardServices.h:

```
#define SPRINGBOARDSERVICES_H

#if __OBJC__


#if __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>
#include <Availability.h>

    mach_port_t SBSSpringBoardServerPort();

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Application launching
    /// Launch an application given the display ID.
    /// Equivalent to -[UIApplication launchApplicationWithIdentifier:suspended:].
    /// @return 0 on success, nonzero on failure. Feed the result to SBSApplicationLaunchingErrorString() to get the error string.
    int SBSLaunchApplicationWithIdentifier(CFStringRef displayIdentifier, Boolean suspended) __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA, __IPHONE_3_0);

    /// Launch an application for debugging.
    /// The parameters are not known yet...
    int SBSLaunchApplicationForDebugging(void* unknown, ...) __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA, __IPHONE_3_0);

    /// Get the error string from error code returned by SBSLaunchApplicationWithIdentifier().
    CFStringRef SBSApplicationLaunchingErrorString(int error);

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Watchdog assertion

    typedef struct __SBSWatchdogAssertion* SBSWatchdogAssertionRef;

    CFTypeID SBSWatchdogAssertionGetTypeID();
    void SBSWatchdogAssertionCancel(SBSWatchdogAssertionRef assertion);
    SBSWatchdogAssertionRef SBSWatchdogAssertionCreateForPID(CFAllocatorRef allocator, pid_t pid);
    int SBSWatchdogAssertionRenew(SBSWatchdogAssertionRef assertion);
    CFTimeInterval SBSWatchdogAssertionGetRenewalInterval(SBSWatchdogAssertionRef assertion);

#pragma mark -

    CFArrayRef SBSCopyApplicationDisplayIdentifiers(Boolean onlyActive, Boolean unknown);

    CFStringRef SBSCopyIconImagePathForDisplayIdentifier(CFStringRef dispIden);
    CFStringRef SBSCopyLocalizedApplicationNameForDisplayIdentifier(CFStringRef dispIden);

    /*
     SB functions should be generated by MIG!

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark SB functions - Media
    void SBSetMediaVolume(mach_port_t port, int volume) __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA, __IPHONE_3_0);

    void SBSetDisableNowPlayingHUD(mach_port_t port, Boolean disable) __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA, __IPHONE_3_0);
    void SBSetNowPlayingInformation(mach_port_t port, void* info);

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark SB functions - Accessibility
    void SBSetZoomTouchEnabled(mach_port_t port, Boolean enable) __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA, __IPHONE_3_0);
    void SBSetDisplayColorsInverted(mach_port_t port, Boolean inverted) __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA, __IPHONE_3_0);

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark SB functions - Remote
    void SBApplicationSetSimpleRemoteRoutingPriority(mach_port_t port, int priority) __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA, __IPHONE_3_0);

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark SB functions - Watchdog

    void SBCancelWatchdogAssertionForProcess(mach_port_t port, pid_t pid, void* unknown);

    void SBReloadApplication(mach_port_t port) __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA, __IPHONE_3_0);
     */


#if __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif
```

and here is my code I am using in my ViewController.m file:

```
#import "SpringBoardServices.h"


-(IBAction)AdSheed {

    SBSLaunchApplicationWithIdentifier(CFSTR("com.apple.preferences"), false);



}
```

Does anyone have an idea how I can solve this problem?

Comment: You can [see this similar answer I posted](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15455831/119114) on how to use `SBSLaunchApplicationWithIdentifier()`. The problem is that it **also** requires your app to have a special entitlement, and to do that, I think requires a jailbreak (at least, I don't know how to add it anymore, without the jailbreak).

Answer (score 1):

It's a private framework. you're not supposed to use it. You cannot do this without using schemes.

Comment: I am not planing to submit it to the AppStore this is for Weblin, iPwnStore, iClaashStore, WebBreak,… for the alternatives AppStores. And there must be a way because a good german Developer told me that it is possible.

Comment: In that case I recommend you ask on goodgermandeveloperoverflow.com