# iOS 6.x open command line on jailbreak

Tags: ios, command, jailbreak

Before iOS 6.x, I used `open package_id` to open a app from command line on a iOS device.
On iOS 6.x if i use this command SpringBoard crashes.
Open is available from BigBoss and the author is Conrad Kramer.

Is there an alternative or a fix for the `open` command from BigBoss?

Comment: does it need to be a command line tool, or are you trying to write an app, and do it *programmatically*?

Comment: command line tool, but if it can be done programatically then i can write a command line tool :D

Comment: I'm having the same problem in iOS 6.1. The `open` tool is very useful for developing jailbreak apps (post-build deployment script).

Answer (score 7):

### Update:

It looks like the original `/usr/bin/open` has been updated for iOS 6 on Cydia, so I recommend you try that first.

---

### Original Answer:

I miss `open`, too!  But, until it gets updated for iOS 6, you can just build your own non-graphical app (just a `main` program, not a `UIApplicationMain()`) and do the same thing yourself.

I'll skip over parsing command line arguments from `int main(int argc, char *argv[]`, but once you know the *Bundle Id* (`CFBundleIdentifier`) of the app you want to open, open the **SpringBoardServices** private framework, and use it to launch the app:

```
#include <dlfcn.h>
#define SBSERVPATH "/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices"

-(void) openApp: (NSString*) bundleId {

    // the SpringboardServices.framework private framework can launch apps,
    //  so we open it dynamically and find SBSLaunchApplicationWithIdentifier()
    void* sbServices = dlopen(SBSERVPATH, RTLD_LAZY);
    int (*SBSLaunchApplicationWithIdentifier)(CFStringRef identifier, Boolean suspended) = dlsym(sbServices, "SBSLaunchApplicationWithIdentifier");
    int result = SBSLaunchApplicationWithIdentifier((__bridge CFStringRef)bundleId, false);
    dlclose(sbServices);
}
```

This code requires the `com.apple.springboard.launchapplications` entitlement for your command line program to use it successfully, as the `mobile` user.  [See here for adding an entitlement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14885266/119114).  You'd need an entitlements.xml file for your executable, like this:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>com.apple.springboard.launchapplications</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

And then sign it with

```
ldid -Sentitlements.xml MyCommandLineTool
```

**Note:** I haven't tested this, but [this answer states that an alternative to using entitlements is to run the command as root](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10211200/119114).