# Open iOS application via Bundle Identifier

Tags: iphone, ios, jailbreak

Is there a way to open an application via `bundle identifier`on jailbroken iOS ?

Comment: Yes, but I'm pretty sure this has been asked and answered already.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS 6.x open command line on jailbreak](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15202441/ios-6-x-open-command-line-on-jailbreak)