# how to open a special view of Preferences in a jailbreak tweak?

Tags: ios, settings, jailbreak, tweak

i am working on a jailbreak Tweak, and i need to open a special view of Settings
i googled a lot and after iOS5.1,

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs://"]];
```

does not work anymore. how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

If this code is running on a jailbroken phone, you can use the [technique I show in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15455831/119114) to *programmatically* open an app by its bundle identifier.

Basically, you are using the `SBSLaunchApplicationWithIdentifier()` private API in the SpringBoardServices.framework.

If this is for an **app**, be sure to follow the instructions in my answer to add the `com.apple.springboard.launchapplications` entitlement to your app.

If your code is injected into SpringBoard itself as some sort of a *tweak*, then I don't think you need to worry about adding the entitlement.

The bundle identifier for the Preferences.app is `com.apple.Preferences`, so that's the string you pass to `SBSLaunchApplicationWithIdentifier()`, as shown in my linked answer.

---

*Note: my assumption is that you are asking this question for iOS 6, since there isn't a stable jailbreak out for iOS 7 yet.*

Comment: thanks @Nate, but this just open the app, not the special view like "General" of Settings

Comment: @user2575599, I can't read minds :). You didn't say that you wanted to open the General page in your question.

Answer (score 0):

The settings app url schemes are gone in iOs 5.1, you should recreate the desired URL scheme hooking the method `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation`

for the preference app. Using pseudo-code it should be

```
if(url contain @"general") { go to general section }  else %orig;
```

you could go to a section by calling the didSelect method of the preferences' tableView for example