# SpringboardServices : Get application name from application identifier

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, springboard

How can i use  `SpringboardServices`, currently it is showing **linking error**.

```
NSString* appName = (__bridge NSString *)(SBSCopyLocalizedApplicationNameForDisplayIdentifier((__bridge CFStringRef)(runningAppId)));*
```

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14144848/how-to-launch-applications-without-url-schemes-and-without-touching-the-icon-on

Comment: @Mani: I dont want to submit my app on App Store, this is an enterprise application. So i have to use this PrivateFramework. I have seen the link you shared. IT will not solve my problem.

Comment: then you can look at this. take time and understand about this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5906180/return-a-list-of-running-background-apps-processes-in-ios